# Remove Layered navigation - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I would link to remove all the layered navigation filters from left side of `Magento 2`, using `xml` Please guide me

Comment: Can anybody provide a full list of referanceContainer names that can be removed/positioned

Answer (score 16):

Add this to your theme `default.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
```

**OR**

Add this on **Admin Panel > Products > Categories > YOUR PAGE > Design**

```
<referenceContainer name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
```

[image]

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-remove-layered-navigation/)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by just admin category settings.

In admin panel of your Magento, go to `Products > Categories`, then select the category on the left.

Now on the right side, select `Display Settings` tab, and from the settings that appear make sure that the `Is Anchor` option is set to `No`.

Do this for all categories you want to hide Layered navigation from. Clear Cache and do re-index if required.

Comment: @parasarora1303: Does this helps to solve ?

Answer (score 3):

To remove layered navigation from search

```
<referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.leftnav" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove this via Layout Update XML in the CMS (`Products > Categories > Design`) use

```
<referenceContainer name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
```

Note it has to be `referenceContainer` and not `referenceBlock` when used here.

Answer (score -1):

Well you could remove it's 'module' completely altogether from the system without any tweaking:

NOTE: Please be extremely careful with this procedure, as it can break things, if it does, then please check my last comment-line below to restore.

1) Go to the command line, where Magento is.

2) run:

> php bin/magento module:uninstall Magento_LayeredNavigation

3) Confirm (Yes, Yes,... )

4) Remove the old cache/and generated content:

> rm -rf var/cache/* pub/static/frontend generated/code/*

5) Re-Index:

> php bin/magento index:reindex

6) Clear the cache:

> php bin/magento  index:reindex

4) If needed, clear the cache and refresh.

---

if you miss it, and want it back, or if removing causes problems, then re-enable it using:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_LayeredNavigation
```

I hope this helps.

Regards
Heider

Comment: Would it be preferable to _disable_ the module with `php bin/magento module:disable Magento_LayeredNavigation` rather than removing it?